# Python: creating a list from button values using tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I am trying to make a GUI for my mastermind Game. If you do not know the rules you can find them here [Mastermind Rules](http://www.industrious.com/mastermind/gamerules.html). The problem I am having is trying to get the buttons to only add their respective color to the list ONCE per click (right now it is adding that color 4 times). The code I have so far is below. Any help would be greatly appreciated and thank you in advance.

```
from tkinter import *
class Mastermind(Frame):

    def __init__(self, master):
        self.master = master     
        self.label = Label(master, text = "Colors:")
        self.label.grid(row=0, column=0)

        self.red_button = Button(root, text="red", command = lambda: self.get_guesses("red"))
        self.orange_button = Button(text="orange", command = lambda: self.get_guesses("orange"))
        self.yellow_button = Button(text="yellow", command = lambda: self.get_guesses("yellow"))
        self.green_button = Button(text="green", command = lambda: self.get_guesses("green"))
        self.blue_button = Button(text="blue", command = lambda: self.get_guesses("blue"))
        self.purple_button = Button(text="purple", command = lambda: self.get_guesses("purple"))

        self.red_button.grid(row=1, column=0)
        self.orange_button.grid(row=2, column=0)
        self.yellow_button.grid(row=3, column=0)
        self.green_button.grid(row=4, column=0)
        self.blue_button.grid(row=5, column=0)
        self.purple_button.grid(row=6, column=0)


    def get_guesses(self, color):

        guessList = []
        while len(guessList)<4:
            if color == "red":
                guess = ('red')
            if color == "orange":
                guess = ('orange')
            if color == "yellow":
                guess = ('yellow')
            if color == "green":
                guess = ('green')
            if color == "blue":
                guess = ('blue')
            if color == "purple":
                guess = ('purple')

            guessList.append(guess)
        print(guessList)
        return guessList
```

Comment: If you don't want the code to execute four times, don't have a `while len(guessList)<4` loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `if` in place of `while`.
And use variable `self.guessList`

```
def __init__(self, master):
    self.guessList = []


def get_guesses(self, color):

    if len(self.guessList) < 4:
        self.guessList.append(color)

    print(self.guessList)
```

Answer (score 0):

Get rid of the `while` loop in `get_guesses`. Make it so that `guessList` is an instance variable instead of a local variable (so move it into your `__init__` method and prefix it with `self.`).

Then to do the waiting until your list has 4 guesses in it, I would just stick an `if` section at the end of `get_guesses` that contains the special additional logic which should only be done once 4 guesses are recorded.